# Conversion Type Error CGPoint to CGFloat in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
   var _deltaTime = NSTimeInterval()

   var _pointsPerScndSpeed = Double()

   var bgVelocity: CGPoint = CGPointMake(_pointsPerScndSpeed, 0.0)

      //Cannot convert the expression's to type 'CGFloat'

     var amToMove:CGPoint = CGPointMake(bgVelocity.x * _deltaTime, bgVelocity.y * _deltaTime)

       //Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied Arguments
```

Comment: @Yatheesha: It compiles on 64-bit, but not on 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The members of `CGPoint` have the the type `CGFloat`, which is a `Float` on the 32-bit
architecture and `Double` on the 64-bit architecture.
Swift does not implicitly convert types. You can either use `CGFloat`
consistently in your code, or add explicit casts:

```
var bgVelocity: CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGFloat(_pointsPerScndSpeed), 0.0)
var amToMove:CGPoint = CGPointMake(bgVelocity.x * CGFloat(_deltaTime), bgVelocity.y * CGFloat(_deltaTime))
```